# Need two slanted lines to form a point and act as a break for the page using CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css

As I can't upload images due to reputation points here goes me trying to explain it.

I have 2 div's than need to be separated by two slanted lines coming down towards each other forming a point in the middle. The jsfiddle will show you what I mean.

I tried this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/RZ4b8/7/

However I don't know how to make it responsive as the values are set for the border-left-width property and only works for specific browser widths. Below is the code;

```
.top-border { width: 100%; position: relative; left: 0; }
.top-border-left { border-top-width: 30px; border-right-width: 0; border-bottom-width: 0; border-left-width: 800px; border-color: transparent transparent transparent #ffffff; float: left; }
.top-border-left { border-style: solid solid inset solid; width: 0; height: 0; }
.top-border-right { border-top-width: 0; border-right-width: 0; border-bottom-width: 30p x; border-left-width: 800px; border-color: transparent transparent #ffffff transparent; float: right; }
.top-border-right { border-style: inset solid solid solid; width: 0; height: 0; }
```

Comment: Are you looking for thin lines or solid fill?

Comment: I reckon the height will be specified and maybe at the mobile level will be changed with some media queries.

Comment: If it is thin lines then I guess that would retain the background from the other DIV's right?

Comment: Here is a link to the website I am working on http://www.insiderinternetsuccess.com/store/ thanks!

Comment: To make this work, the border widths would need to be %, which is not doable in CSS at this time (values must be explicit, px or em ...).  The best approach would be to create a SVG graphic and then embedded in a div between your two text blocks.

Comment: I was thinking of using an image however I wasn't sure how to tackle it as I need the background from the 2 div's to show - unless I create an image for each "break" sort to speak..

Comment: The code I am using is from this website - http://oceanhtml.oceanplazatheme.com/html/index.html however they have made it "responsive"

Comment: What these guys are doing is using JavaScript/jQuery to calculate the border widths to get the effect that you see. Can't be done by CSS alone... but not too bad using jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### jQuery/CSS Solution for a Flexible Triangular Box

In the simplest case, start with this **HTML**:

```
<div class="div1">text 1</div>
<div class="top-border">
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
<div class="div2">text 2</div>
```

and apply this **CSS**:

```css
.div1 {
    background: purple;
    height: 50px;
}
.div2 {
    background: red;
    height: 50px;
}
.top-border {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.top-border .inner {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 50px solid lightgray; /* controls the height of the triangle */
    border-left: 100px solid transparent; /* these default values are reset 
                                             by the jQuery script */
    border-right: 100px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

and use the following **jQuery** script to set the correct border widths:

```js
function setTriangleWidth() {
    var baseWidth = $(".top-border").width() / 2.0;

    $(".top-border .inner").css({
        "border-left-width": baseWidth + "px",
            "border-right-width": baseWidth + "px"
    });
}

$(window).resize(function(){setTriangleWidth();});

$(document).ready(setTriangleWidth())
```

Demo fiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/Gs2pc/

This demonstrates the basic concept.  If you want the triangle to overlap the red text box, then you can use absolute positioning or a negative margin, for example:

```css
.div2.ex2 {
    margin-top: -50px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
    padding-top: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for this - this looks like it can work with a bit of editing. If I get stuck I will drop a message!

Comment: Marc - your solution helped me with regards to resizing but now I have another! The triangle needs inherit the same background as the first div. I updated the jsfiddle to show you what i mean http://jsfiddle.net/Gs2pc/4/

Comment: What you want may or may not be doable depending on a few details.  For example, you could do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/Gs2pc/8/ where you apply the same background image to the triangle motif.  However, you then need to set the border colors to white and transparent to either hide or show the background in the correct border segment.  A more complete solution may be available but you would really need to post a new question that addresses this new problem.